# Apache POI Excel: ActiveSheet results in multiple sheets in PrintPreview in Libreoffice

Tags: apache-poi

I have a Workbook with 3 different sheets (`A`, `B`, `C`). I create them with the POI in the same order and the whole creation process works quite fine. Somehow I want to have the last sheet as the active one. Therefore I set

```
 workBook.setActiveSheet(2);
```

When I open the workbook with Libreoffice 7.1 than `C` is displayed as the active one. When I open print preview the first sheet (`A`) is always included. Changing the code to set as well `C` as the selected one won't help.

Is there a way to fix it for Libreoffice? (to have not `A` included in the print preview)

Comment: Not really reproducible without having the whole code and the affected workbook. But there could be multiple sheets selected. So try whether `workBook.getSheetAt(0).setSelected(false); workBook.getSheetAt(1).setSelected(false);` solves the issue.

Comment: The hint with deselecting the first sheet solves my problem! I don't need to select any sheet! I just wonder why the activation not implicitly set the sheet to selected (and deselects the others). Is worth to open an CR (or bug)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Excel` as well as `LibreOffice Calc` multiple sheets can be selected in a workbook. That's a wanted feature because then all settings are applied to all selected sheets. So, in GUI, you can set sheet properties - page settings for example - to multiple sheets the same time. Also changes to cells in GUI are applied to all selected sheets. So you can change cell formatting as well as cell values in multiple sheets the same time.

That's why the `Workbook.setActiveSheet` will set the active sheet - only one sheet can be the active one - but will not deselect sheets. To deselect sheets, `Sheet.setSelected(false)` needs to be used.

So if you want only the active sheet shall be selected, you need deselect all others.

Using `HSSF` `Workbook.setActiveSheet` also does not set the active sheet selected. So you should do this using `Sheet.setSelected(true)`.

In your case:

```
...
workBook.getSheetAt(0).setSelected(false);
workBook.getSheetAt(1).setSelected(false);
workBook.getSheetAt(2).setSelected(true);
workBook.setActiveSheet(2);
...
```

Comment: After poking around in the source code I found `workBook.setSelectedTab(2)` is the shortcut version of manually selecting and deselecting. Thx a lot for the explanation which makes it little bit more clear why it works the way it works.